# Is Star/Snowflake database design good for applications? What is the alternative?

Tags: relational-theory, architecture, database-diagrams, star-schema, snowflake

I need to solve an exercise for a pharmaceutical company, they ask me to create a database structure from scratch given a few informations.

Because I want it to be scalable and "future proof" I decided to follow the `star/snowflake` structure. For now it looks more star than snowflake but the idea is there. I have a particular question about the main Fact Table (**Study**) and how to represent the Dimension Table **Status**.

I came up with 2 options:

- **OPTION 1:** Fact Table **Study** > Foreign Key > Dimension Table **Contract** > Foreign Keys > Dimension Table **Status**.

So we pass through two Dimension Tables in order to represent the **Status** on the Fact Table. I will do that through a `JOIN` in a `view` or whatever...

[image]

- **OPTION 2:** Fact Table **Study** > Foreign Key > Dimension Table **Status**.

This way we link directly the Fact Table (**Study**) to the Dimension Table **Status**.

[image]

Should I go for **Option 1** or **Option 2**?

I'm afraid to link too many Dimension Tables to the Fact Table. This is the first time I try to create a database structure.

Any advice is welcome, any suggestion is welcome, especially from seasoned database architects but also from amateurs.

Thank you

> EDIT: adding a few more info

Thank you @AntC for your question. In fact this is not at all a Data Warehouse scenario, the scenario is that of a pharmaceutical company that needs a new software to track their clinical trial.

But of course the most known schemas are Star/Snowflake and I don't want to use any hierarchical schema. At the same time I want to avoid shapes like triangle, diamond, circle because even if now there are only 100 users who knows what this database will be in 10 years. The idea is to shape something for the long term and in my opinion the Star/Snowflake shape is choose also for normal application as far as I know.

Comment: Is this for a transactional system -- optimise for fast update? Or for a reporting system/data warehouse -- optimise for queries especially aggregations? 'fact table', 'star' vs 'snowflake' is terminology from data warehouse design. If it's a dw then you're taking a data feed from the transactional system; you're not starting "from scratch".

Comment: Thank you @AntC, I added the scenario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Option 2 the `Status_Code` appears as non-key in two tables: `Study`, `Contract`. But which of those [entities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93relationship_model) does it belong to? And what are the relative [cardinalities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93relationship_model#Relationships,_roles_and_cardinalities) of those entities?

Looking at Option 1, the `Status_Code` belongs to the `Contract`; there can be multiple `Study`s for a given `Contract`.

So if you were to adopt option 2, you give OLTP a headache: anytime there's a change in `Status` of a `Contract`, transaction processing needs to replicate that change to all `Study`s, with an obvious risk of getting out of synch. That's called an [update anomaly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization#Objectives).

[Denormalising](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormalization) the model like Option 2 is legitimate in data warehouses, because we want fast reporting. It is unwise in a transaction processing-oriented data model, because of the processing cost and risks of maintaining data in synch.

So for an application focussing on transaction processing, Option 1 is indicated. And yes, you would create a `Join` view `Study` > `Contract` > `Status`.